# SUMR.SI.CONJUNTO usar fechas como criterio, no me toma el último dia del mes

Tags: excel

Siguiendo los consejos de otra página di con la fórmula

```
=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(Hoja1!$E:$E;Hoja1!$A:$A;">="&FECHA(2022;2;1);Hoja1!$A:$A;"<="&FECHA(2022;2;28);Hoja1!$D:$D;Litros!$A16)
```

El tema es que no me suma los importes del 28/02/2022 y eso que en la tabla principal tengo como 4 registros en esa fecha

Lo mismo me ocurre con todos los último día de mes

La hoja general se llama Hoja1 y la hoja donde estoy sumando los litros de combustible (hay varios tipos, por eso 3 criterios) se lama Litros

Mi libro, con las tablas

Y creo que ya di con una solución (ya está en el link). En vez de decirle al segundo criterio menor o igual al ultimo dia de mes, le puse menor estricto al 1 del mes siguiente

https://mega.nz/file/oMcGBaRB#g8xBZ-LtbjrVVWWv2dIyluQsD8NS6JyE0doqNPFJpB8

Comment: Te recomiendo leer cómo agregar [example]

Comment: Hola leo, ¿podrías poner capturas de tus hojas de cálculo? Solo con la fórmula es bastante complicado resolver el problema.

Comment: Ahí agregué lo que faltaba

Comment: Hola leo3487, Las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas, los enlaces a código no están bien vistos, te recomiendo que lo elimines y subas tu código como texto, si ya resolviste tu problema, podrías agregar una respuesta detallando como, y marcarla como aceptada, de ese modo, tu trabajo puede ayudar a otros, gracias.

Comment: El asunto es que, cuando se compara solo con la fecha, compara con el inicio del día, no con el final. Por eso es que es necesario comparar por menor estricto con el día siguiente si es que tus datos tienen información de hora adicional a la del día.

Comment: Gracias Marce.  La solución, siguiendo la fórmula que puse al inicio sería un pequeño arreglo

`=SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(Hoja1!$E:$E;Hoja1!$A:$A;">="&FECHA(2022;2;1);Hoja1!$A:$A;"<"&FECHA(2022;3;1);Hoja1!$D:$D;Litros!$A16)`

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que terminé haciendo